# Joining multiple tables on an already joined table using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have the following which brings back all users in a group along with their posts.

```
$group = Group::where('id', $id)->with('users.posts')->firstOrFail();
```

However, what I need is an additional join on the users to bring back additional (hasMany) information.

What I want is something like this (although this doesn't work)

```
$group = Group::where('id', $id)->with('users.posts,houses')->firstOrFail();
```

The sql would look something like

```
SELECT * FROM groups 
JOIN group_users ON groups.id = group_users.group_id
JOIN users ON users.id = group_users.user_id
JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.id
JOIN house_users ON house_users.user_id = users.id
JOIN houses ON houses.id = house_users.house_id
WHERE groups.id = 123
```

Comment: Try changing your `->with()` to use array syntax, like `->with(["users.posts", "houses"])`, or, separate your strings: `->with("users.posts", "houses")`. I doubt commas are parsed and respected in a single argument passed to `->with()`, but an array, or multiple arguments should work.

Comment: That's the one @TimLewis! `->with(['users.posts','users.houses'])` If you add it as an answer, I can approve.

Comment: Nice! I'll convert that to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a single argument to `with()`, it will look for a relationship with a matching name. Using a single string with a comma won't work as it won't parse and respect it. Since you're trying to use multiple relationships, this needs to be multiple signature, which there are a couple ways to accomplish.

First, array syntax:

```
->with(["users.posts", "houses"])
```

Second, multiple arguments:

```
->with("users.posts", "houses")
```

Either method will specify that you want multiple relationships loaded to your initial query; preference is given to whichever you find easier to read.